# Sizing ValueBox in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am using RMarkdown with Flexidashboards and I want to put four value boxes in same row. I try with this lines of code :

````
Summary {data-orientation=columns} 
===========================================

### BOX1
```{r,eval=TRUE}
valueBox(52,
         icon = "fa-area-chart",color="info")
```

### BOX2

```{r,eval=TRUE}
valueBox(53,
         icon = "fa-area-chart")
```

### BOX3

```{r,eval=TRUE}
valueBox(54, 
         icon = "fa-area-chart")
```

### BOX4

```{r,eval=TRUE}
valueBox(55, 
         icon = "fa-area-chart")
```
````

But unfortunately this value box is wide as the whole page and you can see how is look like on pic below

[image]

So can anybody help me how to put all this boxes in same row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using:

```
Summary {data-orientation=rows}
```

This will put all boxes next to each other on one row, and will put them on several lines if the window is resized.